# Normal Subgroups and their Qualities

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hope all you are healthy and in peace
Suppose N is a normal subgroup of G. If every subgroup of N is normal also in G, could we deduce that centralizer of N in N is N itself ?

Comment: "Centralizer of $N$ in $N$ is $N$ itself" - that's a funny way to say "$N$ is abelian".

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25307/groups-with-all-subgroups-normal) question on MO may be useful.

Comment: In the  quaternion group $\operatorname{Q}_8$, every subgroup is normal.  You can take $G=\operatorname{Q}_8$, or more generally $G =\operatorname{Q}_8 \times K$, where $K$ is an arbitrary group.  For such a group, every subgroup of $\operatorname{Q}_8$ is normal in $G$, however $\operatorname{Q}_8$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. Suppose $G$ is the [Quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) and $N = G$. Then $N$ is normal in $G$. Every subgroup of $G$ is also normal in $G$. But $G$ is not abelian: its centralizer in itself (i.e. its center) is $\{-1, 1\}$.